# SHA512 Hash with Message and Secret Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hmac, sha512

I'm pretty new to google sheets script programming.

I'm trying to compute a SHA512 hash with a message and encrypt it with my secret key.

In PDP equivalent I have: `$sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$message,$secret);`

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

### Sample script :

```
var result = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_512, message, secret);
result = result.map(function(e) {
    var v = (e < 0 ? e + 256 : e).toString(16);
    return v.length == 1 ? "0" + v : v;
}).join("");
Logger.log(result)
```

### Note :

- `hash_hmac` of php is the string of the unsigned hexadecimal.
- At Google Apps Script, the data which was encrypted by `Utilities.computeHmacSignature()` is the bytes array of the signed hexadecimal.
- In order to use this at GAS, it is required to convert the bytes array to the unsigned hexadecimal.

If this was not what you want, can you tell me a sample input and output values? By this, it will be able to do the debug.